Blazor WebApp: SfDataForm show FormItem conditionally
I have a Blazor WebApp with Syncfusion DataForm where I want to display a FormItem depending on what is selected for another FormItem. In my solution, however, when the FormItems are displayed, they are appended at the end and duplicate when you enable and deactivate the condition
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.IsDoubleTank)" ColumnSpan="6" />
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.Volume)" ColumnSpan="3" />
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.Weight)" ColumnSpan="3" />
                @if ((item as Tank).IsDoubleTank)
                {
                    <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.Weight2)" ColumnSpan="3" />
                }
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.WorkingPressure)" ColumnSpan="3" />
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.TestPressure)" ColumnSpan="3" />
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.SerialNumber)" ColumnSpan="6" />
                @if ((item as Tank).IsDoubleTank)
                {
                    <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.SerialNumber2)" ColumnSpan="3" />
                }
                <FormItem Field="@nameof(Tank.TankType)" ColumnSpan="6" />



use @key https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/element-component-model-relationships?view=aspnetcore-8.0

this doesn´t change anything
